# Style only 1 tab of a tab control binded to an itemsource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image]

I have a tab control:

```
 <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
                >
    </TabControl>
```

I want to set the style of only the 1st tab item to some style. Normally, I can do it using this way,

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

But this isn't possible as the tab items are generated from an ItemsSource.

If needed, here is the TabControl ItemTemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=VMName}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx) Property.

Also read this http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/